# A very nice pattern involving prime factorization

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

A while ago I was fiddling around with prime numbers and C++. I defined:
$$f_a(b)= \text{ the amount of numbers } 2^a\leq n<2^{a+1}\text{ with } b \text{ prime factors}$$

I calculated $f_a(b)$ for $2\leq a\leq20$ using a quick and dirty C++ progam and these are the results:
[image]

The horizontal axis represents $b$ and the vertical axis represents $a$. As you can clearly, see a pattern is emerging along the diagonals. It looks like they converge to certain numbers, which form the following sequence:
$$2,5,8,22,47,103,234...$$
the next element maybe being $493$. Also it looks like the ratio a number and the number above it goes to about $2$ for high numbers.

I'm not claiming I've found something special, but I just thought it looked pretty cool. I have some questions though:

1) Does anyone have a solid explanation why this sequence appears and especially why it sort of converges to these numbers?

2) Is there a formula for calculating or otherwise approximating the numbers in this sequence?

3) Why does the ratio between a number and the one above it approach $2$? (or something close to it)

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A092097](https://oeis.org/A092097).

Comment: Is $b$ the number of *distinct* factors or does the multiplicity count ?

Comment: in general, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem

Comment: multiplicity counts